# Batch Variable Evaluation

Tags: time, batch-file, wait

new to batch. I've narrowed down my problem to how batch variables are evaluated I think.

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set timelimit=30
for /F "USEBACKQ tokens=4,6,8" %%a in (`systeminfo ^| qgrep -e "System Up Time:"`) do set /A timepassed=%%a*24*60+%%b*60+%%c

IF "!timepassed!" LEQ "%timelimit%" (

echo %timelimit%

) ELSE (

echo !timepassed!

)
```

When run, I expect the batch to output !timepassed! (1250 currently) however, it always outputs %timelimit% (30), leading me to believe that the LEQ IF is being taken, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: try with "set /a" when you set variables values and and remove quotes in if condition.Now you have string comparation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as suggested, try the following changes in your code

set the variable value using `/A` option

```
set /a timelimit=30
```

and compare the values with

```
IF !timepassed! LEQ !timelimit! (
```